# Is there any way to force an update to systemmodstamp based on a formula/rollup value changing if the record itself wasn't modified?

Tags: formula, roll-up-summary, systemmodstamp

If I have modified a formula or rollup field such that the returned values change on a given record, it doesn't update the record's `systemmodstamp`, since the record itself hasn't been edited.

Is there any trick I could use to force an update to `systemmodstamp` when a formula or rollup is changed, but only on records where the resulting value has changed?

(The reason I'm asking is that we have an external data warehouse connected via API, that wants to stay up to date on changed records. It uses a query based on `systemmodstamp` to refresh itself periodically, but ends up missing changes that are due to formula/rollup edits)

Answer (score 1):

Changes in formula fields will never be reflected in systemodstamp because formula fields don't really hold data.  Instead they are evaluated when the record is being read.

However, changes to **Rollup Summary Fields** should be reflected in the systemmodstamp of their record.  And even if for some reason they're not, you could write logic to be driven by a change in a **Rollup Summary Field** to make some other change in the record & trigger a systemodstamp update.

Note, however, that you cannot do the same thing with formula fields 
because, like I said earlier, they don't really store any data.